# Xcode6 didBeginContact not being called

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, function, collision-detection

I've been trying to get this working for a simple platforming game, but the contact detection has been giving me problems. The didBeginContact function doesn't seem to be getting called when the two nodes touch, here is the code:

```
import SpriteKit
var idleFrames = [SKTexture]()
var walkFrames = [SKTexture]()
var player: SKSpriteNode!
var touchingGround = 0
var idling = 0

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var sp33d: CGVector = CGVectorMake(0.0,0.0)
    var jsp33d: CGFloat = 30
    var gameStick: Joystick?
    var ground: SKSpriteNode?
    let playerskin = character(charnumber: 1)

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    print("hit")
    let firstNode = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode
    let secondNode = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == category.player) && (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == category.ground) {
        touchingGround = 1
    }else{
        touchingGround = 0
    }
}
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -10.0)

    gameStick = Joystick()
    gameStick?.createJoystick(self.scene!.frame.width/4, nameBack: "joystick", nameMoving: "joystick1")
    gameStick!.backPart!.zPosition = 4
    gameStick!.movingPart!.zPosition = 5
    self.addChild(gameStick!.backPart!)
    self.addChild(gameStick!.movingPart!)

    player = self.childNodeWithName("player") as? SKSpriteNode
    ground = self.childNodeWithName("testGround") as? SKSpriteNode
    player?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = category.player
    ground?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = category.ground

    let idleAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "idle.atlas")
    var idleframes = [SKTexture]()
    let numImages = idleAtlas.textureNames.count
    for var i=1; i<=4; i++ {
        let idleframe = "JohnIdle\(i)"
        idleframes.append(idleAtlas.textureNamed(idleframe))
    }
    idleFrames = idleframes
    let firstFrame = idleframes[0]
}

func idleflag() {
    idling = 0
    }

func idlejohn() {
    if sp33d.dx < 1 || sp33d.dx > -1{
        print("boop")
        idling = 1
        player?.runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.animateWithTextures(idleFrames, timePerFrame: 0.4, resize: false, restore: true), count: 1))
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        var nodeTouched = SKNode()
        nodeTouched = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        if nodeTouched.name == "joystick1" {
            gameStick?.movingPart?.position = location
            if location.x > gameStick!.backPart!.position.x + gameStick!.backPart!.frame.width/2{
                gameStick?.movingPart?.position = CGPointMake(gameStick!.backPart!.position.x + gameStick!.backPart!.frame.width/2, gameStick!.movingPart!.position.y)
            }
            if location.y > gameStick!.backPart!.position.y + gameStick!.backPart!.frame.height/2{
                gameStick?.movingPart?.position = CGPointMake(gameStick!.movingPart!.position.x, gameStick!.backPart!.position.y + gameStick!.backPart!.frame.height/2)
            }
        }
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        var nodeTouched = SKNode()
        nodeTouched = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        if nodeTouched.name == "joystick1" {
            gameStick?.movingPart?.position = location
            if location.x > gameStick!.backPart!.position.x + gameStick!.backPart!.frame.width/2{
                gameStick?.movingPart?.position = CGPointMake(gameStick!.backPart!.position.x + gameStick!.backPart!.frame.width/2, gameStick!.movingPart!.position.y)
            }
            if location.y > gameStick!.backPart!.position.y + gameStick!.backPart!.frame.height/2{
                gameStick?.movingPart?.position = CGPointMake(gameStick!.movingPart!.position.x, gameStick!.backPart!.position.y + gameStick!.backPart!.frame.height/2)
            }
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        var nodeTouched = SKNode()
        nodeTouched = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        if nodeTouched.name == "joystick1" {
    let act = SKAction.moveTo(gameStick!.backPart!.position, duration: 0.2)
    gameStick?.movingPart?.runAction(act)
        }
    }
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    let vX = gameStick!.movingPart!.position.x - gameStick!.backPart!.position.x

    var vY: CGFloat = gameStick!.movingPart!.position.y

    if  vY > gameStick!.backPart!.position.y + 20 && touchingGround == 1{
            sp33d = CGVectorMake(vX/13, jsp33d)
    }else{
            sp33d = CGVectorMake(vX/13, 0)
    }
    player?.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(sp33d) 

    idlejohn()
    }
}
```

Here is the bitmask code:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

var charnumber = 0
var charsize = [0: CGSizeMake(80,80)]

struct category {
    static let player: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
    static let ground: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in seems that you haven't initialized the player and the ground physics body

```
player = self.childNodeWithName("player") as? SKSpriteNode
ground = self.childNodeWithName("testGround") as? SKSpriteNode
player?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = category.player
ground?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = category.ground
```

player?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody() //inside brackets choose type of body (rect,circle etc..)
same goes for the ground, if you want the objects the contact, first you need to assign the bodies.

Comment: unfortunately even after doing so, nothing has changed, and the function is still not called

Comment: send me a sample of your project and ill try to see what the problem is